# Take 3 Integers, create a date

Tags: java, date, integer

I am trying to take 3 separate integer inputs (year,month,day) and taking these 3 entries and forming an object of date from them so I can use it to compare other dates.

This is what I have so far, at a loss at where to go from here:

```
public void compareDates() {

    String dayString = txtOrderDateDay.getText();
    String monthString = txtOrderDateMonth.getText();
    String yearString = txtOrderDateYear.getText();

    int day = Integer.parseInt(dayString);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(monthString);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(yearString);
}
```

Many thanks for any help you have to offer.

Comment: have you tried anything else?  looked for a java class named `Date` or anything like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, noticing that months start in zero so we need to subtract one to correctly specify a month:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Or this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month-1, day);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Or this:

```
Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, day).getTime();
```

The first method gives you more control, as it allows you to set other fields in the date, for instance: `DAY_OF_WEEK, DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, DAY_OF_YEAR, WEEK_OF_MONTH, WEEK_OF_YEAR,  MILLISECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, HOUR_OF_DAY` etc.

Finally, for correctly formatting the date as indicated in the comments, do this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String strDate = df.format(date);
```

Comment: Might as well use set(int year, int month, int date), no?

Comment: Thank you so much, this has worked perfectly, but all I am after is:
YYYY/MM/DD

This outputs (as a debug example):
Mon Oct 15 04:29:51 BST 2012

is it possible to trim this down?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Could you expand on how it would be possible for me to format the date I create from the 3 integers and format them as follows:

DD/MM/YYYY

Many Thanks.

Comment: @WickeD

"Try this, noticing that months start in zero so we need to subtract one to correctly specify a month:"

Comment: @speakon I updated my answer with the code for correctly formatting the date. If you only need the date as a String, don't bother and just concatenate a string with "/" in the middle of the year, month and day.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez That's absolute perfect, thank you so much.

I need it initially as a date so I can compare it to a second date, but after that I only need it as a string.

Thank you so much for your help, it has been invaluable.

Sadly I am new and do not have the power to give you reputation.

Comment: @speakon but you can accept the answer, if it was helpful for you ;) . Just click the check mark to its left.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Sorry, if you wouldn't mind one last question. I am taking the newly created entered date and comparing it with the current system date ( I have a method to retrieve this), now I need to make sure that the entered date is NOT: before the current system date OR within ONE DAY of the entered date. How can I go about achieving this comparison? Thank you.

Comment: Use the methods `before()` and `after()` of the `Calendar` class

Comment: I do not why but in my case I also had to subtract 1 to day.https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-date-and-time/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Answer (score 3):

Use [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

```
new GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
```

Comment: Note that month is zero based.

Comment: Yeah, I always wondered why month is zero based but dayOfMonth isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this library, in other to facilitate your life in such task - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Then you are gonna write code like this:

```
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) ;
```

This class offers a bunch of useful methods for comparison and operations like adding minutes... take a look at its documentation [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html)

A bit more about joda-time:

> Joda-Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes. The design allows for multiple calendar systems, while still providing a simple API. The 'default' calendar is the ISO8601 standard which is used by XML. The Gregorian, Julian, Buddhist, Coptic, Ethiopic and Islamic systems are also included, and we welcome further additions. Supporting classes include time zone, duration, format and parsing.